# Реализация увеличение и уменьшения шрифта jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет.
Реализую увеличение и уменьшение размера шрифта на сайте, есть такая разметка.
Не могу понять что делаю не так?

Похоже проблема в этой строке: 
$body.css('font-size', `${fontSize + 10}%`); 
которая должна по идее увеличивать шрифт, но не работает.

```js
$(document)
    .on('click', '#upFont', e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let $body = $('body');
        let fontSize = $body.css('font-size') || 100;

        $body.css('font-size', `${fontSize + 10}%`);

});
```

```html
<div class="weak-panel__font">
   <div>Размер шрифта</div>
   <a class="weak-panel__button" id="downFont" href="#">A -</a>
   <a class="weak-panel__button" id="upFont" href="#">A +</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ПРимерно так:

```js
$(function() {

  $(document)
    .on('click', '#upFont', e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      let fontSize = $('body').css('font-size') || '12px';
      let newSize = parseInt(fontSize) * 1.1;
      $('body').css('font-size', newSize + 'px');

    });

});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="weak-panel__font">
    <div>Размер шрифта</div>
    <a class="weak-panel__button" id="downFont" href="#">A -</a>
    <a class="weak-panel__button" id="upFont" href="#">A +</a>
  </div>

  <div class="text">Текст</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Или вот так, вдруг кому пригодится))

```js
const changeFontSize = operation => {
    let step = 2,
        $body = $('body'),
        fontSize = $body.css('font-size') || '16px';
    $body.css('font-size', operation == 'inc' ?
        `${parseInt(fontSize) + step}px` :
        `${parseInt(fontSize) - step}px`
    );
};

$(document)
    .on('click', '#upFont', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        changeFontSize('inc');
    })
    .on('click', '#downFont', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        changeFontSize('dec');
    });
```